# How have robots developed and how sophisticated might they be in the future?

Tags: robotics

We all know how robots are getting more and sophisticated and more interesting

What is the future of **robotics** in relation to AI, how and how will AI work with robotics in improving to affect our world in a positive way.

Comment: Welcome to AI! I've slightly modified the question to focus on the AI aspects of robotics, so that it will be on-topic for this forum.

Answer (score 1):

> The future of robotics

Companies like Google are doing restless research in robotics whereby machine learning algorithms are applied to empower self driving cars well equipped with computer vision, etc.

The future is so exciting in that it will be an era where artificially intelligence machines can rewrite their own source code and constantly improve upon themselves at an exponential rate -- ASI: *artificial super intelligence*.

Right now, robots like Sophia are using machine learning algorithms to answer or respond to human interactions.

Comment: The next to last paragraph (source code editing and ASI) seems like subjective speculation. Could you provide sources to that? Also to the last paragraph?